# Rails object attributes / db migration defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have a User class in rails with a boolean `is_subscriber` attribute.

My database migration file is structured like this:

```
class AddIsSubscriberToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :is_subscriber, :boolean, :default => false    
  end
end
```

However when I try to create a new instance of User, (using the `create` controller) I get `is_subscriber` to be `nil`. I made sure to include it in my `attr_accessible` listing.

It happens both inside my rails app and in the IRB.

Comment: And what happens when you save your object?

Comment: Doesn't `create` save the object for you by default?

Comment: After saving it in IRB the `is_subscriber` attribute is still `nil`

Comment: ["The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not."](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) so sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.